# How to select rows staring from a row whithout limits?

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows starting from a row like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Type=1 LIMIT $Start,infinity
```

Comment: just query without limits block

Comment: @KoolKabin That will retrieve the entire record set (i.e. from the beginning to the end). The OP want to get records from a specific offset to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to indicate *infinity* in MySQL. To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Type=1 LIMIT $Start, 99999999999999999999;
```

Comment: that exactly what i did before asking ... but it seem this the only way, i thought i will find something more piratical and good.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a primary key say `id`, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Type = 1 AND id >= $Start;
```